# SQL, 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, variables, declare, create-view

I get the following mistake:

> 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.

I'm trying to create a view and to insert date parameters as a variable in the query.
For some reason it doesn't work, any idea how to overcome it?
Here is the query

```
 DECLARE **@StartDate** date='2017-05-29 00:00:00';

GO 
 DECLARE **@EndDate** date='2018-03-04 00:00:00';

GO

 CREATE  VIEW [FG_Cargo] AS

 SELECT c.ContainerName,P.Description,
 WFS.WorkflowStepName,WFB.WorkflowName,  HML.TxnDate, hml.CDOTypeId,
 hml.TxnType

 FROM Container C join HistoryCrossRef HCR on
 (c.ContainerId=HCR.TrackingId) JOIN HistoryMainline HML
 ON(HCR.HistoryId=HML.HistoryId) JOIN Product P ON
 (C.ProductId=P.ProductId) JOIN WorkflowStep WFS ON
 (HML.WorkflowStepId=WFS.WorkflowStepId) JOIN Workflow WF ON
 (WFS.WorkflowId=WF.WorkflowId) JOIN WorkflowBase WFB ON
 (WF.WorkflowBaseId=wfb.WorkflowBaseId)

 WHERE C.ContainerName LIKE('KT%') AND WFS.WorkflowStepName='release
 for shipping' AND  TxnType='6640' AND HML.TxnDate BETWEEN
 **@StartDate** AND **@EndDate** ;

 GO

 SELECT* FROM FG_Cargo
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you get that error, but you cannot create a view with variables.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it. What are my options then? I'd like to create a temp table (but without creating an actual table), that receives 2 dates variables and return a table with information that I'll use in 2 different location.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put variables in a view.  Instead, use an inline table function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_fg_cargo (
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date
) RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (SELECT c.ContainerName, P.Description, WFS.WorkflowStepName, 
               WFB.WorkflowName, HML.TxnDate, hml.CDOTypeId, hml.TxnType
        FROM Container C JOIN
             HistoryCrossRef HCR 
             ON c.ContainerId = HCR.TrackingId JOIN
             HistoryMainline HML
             ON HCR.HistoryId = HML.HistoryId JOIN
             Product P
             ON C.ProductId = P.ProductId JOIN
             WorkflowStep WFS
             ON HML.WorkflowStepId = WFS.WorkflowStepId JOIN
             Workflow WF
             ON WFS.WorkflowId = WF.WorkflowId JOIN
             WorkflowBase WFB
             ON WF.WorkflowBaseId = wfb.WorkflowBaseId
        WHERE C.ContainerName LIKE 'KT%' AND 
              WFS.WorkflowStepName = 'release for shipping' AND 
              TxnType = '6640' AND
              HML.TxnDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
       );
```

You can then use this as:

```
select c.*
from dbo.ufn_fg_cargo('2017-05-29', '2018-03-04') c
```

Comment: When I call the function can I use the variables instead of the actual dates?

Comment: @Vic.D . . . You can pass in the dates that you want, either as literals or as variables.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been stated, you cannot put variables in a view. You have two options. One is to create a function which returns a table (as per the answer provided by @GordonLinoff). The other option, and this depends a lot on the amount of data being represented by the view, is to build the view with all dates, and then do the filtering later.

I would have to confirm this, but I am guessing that using a function would force a rebuild of the table each time you access the function, whereas a view is built / re-built only when the underlying tables / data changes?

**EDIT**

To get rid of the error, and assuming you want a view, you can do the following:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS  
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'FG_Cargo'
)
BEGIN
    EXECUTE('
        CREATE VIEW [dbo].[FG_Cargo]
        AS
            SELECT 
        ...
    ')
END;
GO
```

This ensures that the `CREATE VIEW` statement is definitely the first statement in the query batch, and you avoid the error. You just need to make sure that any quotes in your query are appropriately escaped.

Comment: I don't mind not using a view. I need to create a small table and to use the outcome twice: to pull the SKUs for further usage and the 2nd time to count how many result did I get for a loop. I've tried to create CTE, but for some reason I wasn't able to call use it twice. I dont want to create a table, thus I've decided to create a view for overcome this obstacle and apparently I cant use variable inside. Any other working solution is fine with me. I dont want to create a view and to filter it later and I'm not sure that function is the best solution for me. What other options do I have?

Comment: If you don't need this as a long-term solution, then my comment about efficiency / re-use is moot. I would suggest using the solution proposed by @GordonLinoff, or if you go with the CTE approach, then simply duplicate the CTE code. You can't (to my knowledge) use one CTE for two separate queries.